# Tensorflow ValueError: Shapes (64, 1) and (1, 1) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, siamese-network

I'm trying to build a Siamese Neural Network to analyze the MNIST dataset, however when trying to fit the model to the dataset I encounter this problem according to which I have training data and labels shapes' mismatch. I tried changing the loss function as well as tried to squeeze the labels array, and neither of "solutions" worked.

Here are the train and labels arrays' shapes:

```
pairTrain shape: (120000, 2, 28, 28, 1)
labelTrain shape: (120000, 1)
```

Here's my model:

```
def build_model(input_shape, embedDim=48):
    inputs = Input(input_shape)

    x = Conv2D(64, (2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu", input_shape=input_shape)(inputs)
    x = MaxPooling2D()(x)
    x = Dropout(0.3)(x)

    x = Conv2D(32, (2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu")(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D()(x)
    x = Dropout(0.3)(x)

    x = Conv2D(16, (2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu")(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D()(x)
    x = Dropout(0.3)(x)

    outputs = Flatten()(x)
    outputs = Dense(embedDim)(outputs)

    model = Model(inputs, outputs)

    return model
```

And finally here's the code that generates the error itself:

```
imgA = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
imgB = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))

featA = build_model((28, 28, 1))(imgA)
featB = build_model((28, 28, 1))(imgB)

distance = Lambda(euclidean_distance)([featA, featB])
output = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(distance)

model = Model([imgA, imgB], output)

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
history = model.fit(
    [pairTrain[:, 0], pairTrain[:, 1]], labelTrain,
    validation_data=[[pairTest[:, 0], pairTest[:, 1]], labelTest],
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=10
)

model.save("output/siamese_model")
```

Please help me to resolve the problem.

Comment: Can you give more details? Where the error is coming from exactly?

Comment: @RedaElHail the error message states that the fit function is the source of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce the error using the below code. I suspect that your labels shape is different than the one you reported or it does not contain strictly binary data (0s and 1s) only.

Also, you should use `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy` instead of `tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy` as your labels should be binary with the `sigmoid` activation in the last layer.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Input, Flatten, Dense, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import tensorflow as tf

def build_model(input_shape, embedDim=48):
    inputs = Input(input_shape)

    x = Conv2D(64, (2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu", input_shape=input_shape)(inputs)
    x = MaxPooling2D()(x)
    x = Dropout(0.3)(x)

    x = Conv2D(32, (2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu")(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D()(x)
    x = Dropout(0.3)(x)

    x = Conv2D(16, (2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu")(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D()(x)
    x = Dropout(0.3)(x)

    outputs = Flatten()(x)
    outputs = Dense(embedDim)(outputs)

    model = Model(inputs, outputs)

    return model

imgA = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
imgB = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))

featA = build_model((28, 28, 1))(imgA)
featB = build_model((28, 28, 1))(imgB)

distance = Lambda(lambda x: x[0]-x[1])([featA, featB])
output = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(distance)

model = Model([imgA, imgB], output)

pairTrain =  tf.random.uniform((10, 2, 28, 28, 1))
labelTrain = tf.random.uniform(shape=(10, 1), minval=0, maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)

pairTest =  tf.random.uniform((10, 2, 28, 28, 1))
labelTest = tf.random.uniform(shape=(10, 1), minval=0, maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
history = model.fit(
    [pairTrain[:, 0], pairTrain[:, 1]], labelTrain,
    validation_data=[[pairTest[:, 0], pairTest[:, 1]], labelTest],
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=10
)

model.save("output/siamese_model")
```

```
Epoch 1/10
1/1 [==============================] - 2s 2s/step - loss: 0.7061 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.6862 - val_accuracy: 0.7000
Epoch 2/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 80ms/step - loss: 0.7882 - accuracy: 0.4000 - val_loss: 0.6751 - val_accuracy: 0.6000
Epoch 3/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 81ms/step - loss: 0.6358 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.6755 - val_accuracy: 0.6000
Epoch 4/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 79ms/step - loss: 0.7027 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.6759 - val_accuracy: 0.6000
Epoch 5/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 82ms/step - loss: 0.6970 - accuracy: 0.4000 - val_loss: 0.6752 - val_accuracy: 0.6000
Epoch 6/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 83ms/step - loss: 0.7564 - accuracy: 0.4000 - val_loss: 0.6779 - val_accuracy: 0.6000
Epoch 7/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 73ms/step - loss: 0.7123 - accuracy: 0.6000 - val_loss: 0.6818 - val_accuracy: 0.6000
```

Comment: I tried to use your technique of arbitrary data as a training/labeling data just to experiment and try to figure out the problem, and it turned out the problem was in correlation of the data amount (120000 samples) and the batch size (64). Frankly I don't clearly understand why it yields an error, seems like but now it works, though the model seems like doesn't learn as its loss/accuracy don't change lol. Anyway thanks a lot